# Creating a list with the links to all the documents inside a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, document

I am using SharePoint online. We have a large document library with PDF of contract files that we need to catalogue. We have a excel spreadsheet that contains all the info we need and importing this into SharePoint lists is a breeze. We have also uploaded all the documents into a document library on the same site. But how can we create a link to these files in bulk from the list?

There is only one contract on each line, and we need a link to each document in the list.

Is there a way to create a lists of links to all the documents in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Export to Excel to get list of links to all the documents in a folder.

[image]